# Error with wildcard on Generics

Tags: java, android, generics, android-studio, wildcard

I am developing an app with Android Studio.

I have an error when I try to put an `Object` in an `ArrayMap`.

```
private ArrayMap<String, ? extends Tracker> trackers;

public void addTracker(@NonNull Tracker tracker) {
    trackers.put(tracker.getName(), tracker);
}
```

I want my to add to my `ArrayMap` any kind of object which inherits from the class `Tracker`

The IDE says it cannot resolve the `put` method for arguments  `(String, Tracker)`

Any idea why?

Comment: try private ArrayMap<String, Object extends Tracker> trackers

Comment: what this declaration allows is to do `trackers = new ArrayMap<String, Thing>();`  where `Thing extends Tracker`. Since this is authorized, then `trackers.add(tracker.getName(), tracker)` is not allowed, because `trackers` possibly is more restrictive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 2nd generic parameter for `trackers` could be any type of `Tracker` so the compiler prevents a direct instance being added. You could declare it as

```
private ArrayMap<String, Tracker> trackers;
```

Comment: If I do as you said, then I cannot put any object which inherits from Tracker, can I?

Comment: why not?  `ArrayMap<String, Tracker>` will allow all subclass types

Comment: It works, but I don't understand why. From Oracle doc: `Given that Integer is a subtype of Number, what is the relationship between List<Integer> and List<Number>? List<Integer> is not a subtype of List<Number> and, in fact, these two types are not related.` So I am expected `ArrayMap<String, Tracker>` is not a parent of `ArrayMap<String, CustomTracker>` if `CustomTracker` inherits from `Tracker`

Comment: @DanieleVitali that quote refers to generic type declarations but its ok to pass in any type of `Tracker` that has been declared in a non-generic way...

Comment: Thank you @Reimeus. One more question after your last comment. What's the difference between `Map<String, Tracker>` and `Map<String, ? super Tracker>` then?

Comment: Essentially, theyre the same :)